# how to rotate the joints of an URDF Model using DAT.GUI in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, dat.gui

```
 import * as THREE from "three";
 import OrbitControls from "three-orbitcontrols";
 import URDFLoader from "urdf-loader";
 import * as  dat from 'dat.gui';


const gui = new dat.GUI();
const controls = {
    BJ: 0, // Joint angles for each joint
    
};
gui.add(controls, 'BJ', -180, 180).name('Base Joint'); // Adjust range as needed

class RobotScene extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            sliderData: {}
        };
        // Setting up the initial state and references
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.camera = null;
        this.renderer = null;
        this.robotBase = null; // Reference to the robot's base



        this.initScene();
        this.addRobot();
        this.addControls();
        this.startAnimationLoop();
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowResize);
    }


    initScene() {
        // Set up camera
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            75, // fov = field of view
            window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, // aspect ratio
            0.1, // near plane
            1000 // far plane
        );
        this.camera.position.z = 5; // Move the camera back

        // Set up renderer
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement); // Append to the document body

        // Set up orbit controls
        new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);

        // Set up lighting
        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
        this.scene.add(ambientLight);
        const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
        directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1);
        this.scene.add(directionalLight);
    }

    addRobot() {
        const loader = new URDFLoader();
        loader.load("/robot_active.urdf", (robot) => {
            this.robotBase = robot; // Assuming the robot base is the root of the loaded URDF model
            this.scene.add(robot);
        });
    }

    updateRobotJoints() {
        if (this.robotBase) {
            // Replace these names with the actual joint names from your URDF file
            const BJ = this.robotBase.getObjectByName('BJ');
            

            if (BJ) {
                const BJRotationRadians =  THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(controls.BJ);
                BJ.rotation.z = THREE.MathUtils.clamp(BJRotationRadians, -2.0944, 2.0944);
            }

           
        }
    }




    startAnimationLoop = () => {

        this.updateRobotJoints(); // Update the robot joints in each frame
        // Animation loop
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
        
        // Update any animations or rendering operations here

        // Keep looping
        this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.startAnimationLoop);
    };

    handleWindowResize = () => {
        // Update camera and renderer on window resize
        const width = window.innerWidth;
        const height = window.innerHeight;
        this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
        this.camera.aspect = width / height;
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    };

    render() {
        return null; // No need to render anything in this component
    }
}

export default RobotScene;``

`
```

The above is my code where i am able to load my urdf and able to add control using DAT.GUI but i am not being able to make movement of the joints and neither my urdf model is being rotated in the application.
I don't know what is the problem in the code that slider is not being able to get connect with the joints and the movement is not happening
If i am able to achieve this it will work as a simulation tool for me

Comment: Please create a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). Also, if able, please provide your 3D model. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: i have the 3D model in the URDF format , if u want i can provide the snippet

Comment: Please do. Since a URDF file is just an XML, you can post it on pastebin.com, if the file is yours or open-source, and if you have no objections to the file being available online for other people. Open the file in a text editor of any kind, copy its contents and paste them on pastebin.com.

Comment: i cant provide the urdf file in any open source as it will be against my NDA , can u help me in rotating the model , then i can provide it here

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately, I can offer no guarantees that I, or anyone else, will be able to help without a URDF file of any kind. Would it be possible to provide a similar file, which will not violate the terms of your NDA, and which also exhibits the same problem as your original file? Then we can see if the problem is within the code or within the file / model.